Data transfer into multiple sheets from userform
Am new to vba and am trying to transfer data into activesheet/sh.name by activating the sheet but getting error. I also need a code to display the list of months in a combox.
thank you for your assistance.
enter image description here
Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()
targetSheet = ComboBox1.Value
If targetSheet = "" Then
Exit Sub
End If
Worksheets(targetSheet).Activate
lastrow = sh.Name.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(x1Up).Row
sh.Name.Cells(lastrow + 1, 1).Value = TextBox1.Value
sh.Name.Cells(lastrow + 1, 2).Value = TextBox2.Value
sh.Name.Cells(lastrow + 1, 3).Value = ComboBox2.Value
sh.Name.Cells(lastrow + 1, 4).Value = TextBox4.Value
MsgBox ("Data is added Successfully")
TextBox1.Value = ""
TextBox2.Value = ""
ComboBox2.Value = ""
TextBox4.Value = ""
Worksheets("MASTERSHEET").Activate
Worksheets("MASTERSHEET").Cells(1, 1).Select
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
Unload UserForm1
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

Dim sh As Worksheet

    ComboBox1.Clear 'Clear combobox
    For Each sh In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        ComboBox1.AddItem sh.Name
    Next sh

End Sub



sh.Name.Cells() looks to be the culprit.  Sheets("Name"), etc., should be the reference, or just Sheets(number)... you also have a significant faux pas with '.cells() ' and inside not having '.rows.count', as you want to qualify each.  a with statement would benefit you

This should resolve the issue related to your sheet name and qualifying:
With sheets(targetsheet)
    dim lastRow as long:  lastRow = .cells(.rows.count,1).end(xlup).row
    .cells(lastRow+1, 1).value = Textbox1.Value 'do this for each
    '...
End with

You also do not need to "activate" the sheet to write to it.

Thank you Cyril for the corrections. I wanted to activate the active sheet from the combox then input data and the hit the transfer button. The code works fine but the moment you select the active sheet it says data submitted sucussfully. Any advice
